# Accessing StringGrid from another Form

Tags: delphi, insert, access-violation, stringgrid

**Edit the body for more details.**

I have a Form called ENP, defined in the EnpView unit. The ENP form, is created and shown from the handler event of a click a toolbar item in the Main Form (TPrincipal).

```
procedure TPrincipal.ENP1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TENP.Create(self).Show();
end;
```

Enp form knows (in public declaration) clearGrid() message.

ENP Form have a TStringGrid called StringGrid. And a button called "Add". When click "Add" button other Form is created and shown: AddEnp form, defined in EnpViewAdd unit.

```
procedure TENP.opAgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAddEnp.Create(self).Show();
end;
```

The AddEnp form, have any TEdits. The values of the inputs must be adding in the EnpView.StringGrid.

I try this:

```
implementation

uses
  EnpView, Main;
procedure TAddEnp.AgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  { Agrego el nodo xml }
  Globals.Xml.agregarMuestra(muestra.Text);
  Globals.Xml.insertEnp(muestra.Text,golpes.Text,metros.Text);

  { Send messages to EnpView Form }
  ENP.clearGrid();
  ENP.populateGrid();

end;
```

ClearGrid messages fails in line 1, with access violation:

```
procedure TENP.clearGrid();
begin
  Self.StringGrid.RowCount := 2;
  Self.StringGrid.Rows[1].Clear();
end;
```

The clearGrid methods works if is send within the class. Any ideas ?.

Comment: ENP is a form inside the first unit. ENP already created when executes the second form.

Comment: what is the declaration of `stringgrid` ? is it assigned ? put the breakpoint on the problem line and before executing it evaluate `pointer(Self)` and `pointer(Self.stringgird)` whether they have any reasonable value

Comment: also copy and paste here the full text of access violation error, with all the numbers and reasoning.
additionally you may try to set the "use debug DCUs" option with project settings, but the error is probably on your side, not inside VCL

Comment: Access violation in address 004ED82D in module "SiGAS.exe". Read of address 00000388

Comment: when are you calling that procedure?

Comment: In the on click event, of a button of the second Form.

Comment: "Read of address 00000388" almost certainly a nil pointer de-reference. The program tries to read a property of object, that does not exist. So please, do report the values of pointers as i asked above! Don't ignore the important questions please.

Comment: Where is `Enp` being created? Is it auto-created? Or are you creating it in code yourself? (Just adding the unit name to a `uses` clause does not create an instance of the form.) Please [edit] to add that information; it's important if you want us to try and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property named, for instance, ENPForm in TAddENP and assign the ENP form just after creating it. Declare it as follows:

```
TAddENP = class(TForm)
private
  FENPForm: TENP;

// all of your already existing declarations

public
  property ENPForm: TENP read FENPForm write FENPForm;
end;
```

Now that you have a possible reference to ENP form, you can use it as you like.

During the creation of TAddENP form, do as follows:

```
procedure TENP.opAgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  addForm: TAddENP;
begin
  addForm := TAddEnp.Create(Self);
  addForm.EnpForm := Self;
  addForm.Show;
end;
```

Now you created the second form and gave it a secure reference to the first one. They can now talk to each other safely.

I advise you to avoid having one form operating other one´s components, because this increses the dependency between them. Instead, declare public methods to do that, so the forms will depend on their interfaces, not their implementations.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*From your question (I added `code-style` to make it more clear):*

> I have a Form called `ENP`, defined in the `EnpView` unit. The `ENP` form,
>   is created and shown from the handler event of a click a toolbar item
>   in the Main Form (`TPrincipal`).

```
procedure TPrincipal.ENP1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TENP.Create(self).Show();
end;
```

This does nothing with your `ENP` form variable.
You create an instance of the `TENP` form class and show it using `Show`, but the `ENP` variable is not assigned.
You cannot assign the instance to the `ENP` variable, as each button click creates a new instance (so you have multiple instances of `TENP`) around.

Then you create a convoluted depedency of a `TAddEnp` instance and the (never assinged `ENP` variable).
You do this by creating a `TAddEnp` instance (why `TAddEnp` here, and not `TAddENP`?) show it using `Show` (giving the users the opportunity to go back to the `TENP` instance and again click on the `opAgregar` button to create more instances of `TAddEnp`):

```
procedure TENP.opAgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAddEnp.Create(self).Show();
end;
```

Followed by having the `TAddEnp` depend on the `ENP` variable:

```
procedure TAddEnp.AgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
//...
  ENP.clearGrid();
  ENP.populateGrid();
end;
```

This will indeed fail:

> ClearGrid messages fails in line 1, with access violation:

```
procedure TENP.clearGrid();
begin
  Self.StringGrid.RowCount := 2;
  Self.StringGrid.Rows[1].Clear();
end;
```

The reason is that `ENP` is not assigned (by default it will be `nil`), so inside `clearGrid`, the `Self` will also be `nil`.

**Solutions you could implement**

1. Keep a single instance of `TENP` and `TAddEnp` around, using `ShowModal` to force modality to prevent the user from clicking on the same buttons multiple times.
2. Keep your existing `Show` behaviour, but binding each `TAddEnp` instance to the `TENP` instance it was created from.

For the first solution, your code will become this:

```
procedure TPrincipal.ENP1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ENP := TENP.Create(Application);
  ENP.ShowModal();
  ENP.Release();
  ENP := nil;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TENP.opAgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddEnp := TAddEnp.Create(Application);
  AddEnp.ShowModal();
  AddEnp.Release();
  AddEnp := nil;
end;
```

The second will take more effort, as you need to prevent the use of the existing variables.

- Delete the `ENP` variable.
- Delete the `AddENP` variable.

Fix the `self` -> `Self` in the methods

```
procedure TPrincipal.ENP1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TENP.Create(Self).Show();
end;
```

and

```
procedure TENP.opAgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAddEnp.Create(Self).Show();
end;
```

Here add the dependency:

```
procedure TAddEnp.AgregarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ENP: TENP;
begin
//...
  ENP := Owner as TENP; // Owner will be of type TENP because of the Create(Self) in the ENP1Click method
  ENP.clearGrid();
  ENP.populateGrid();
end;
```